# Creating dynamic date using javascript where the date is in single digit should append a "0" before them

Tags: javascript

I am creating a JavaScript for dynamic date, my code is as below.

#### HTML:

```
<span id="spanDate"></span>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
var months = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000 * 3600 * 24));
document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = tomorrow.getDate() + "/" + months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + "/" + tomorrow.getFullYear();
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4e87x6k/)

I am getting the date printed, but when it comes to single digit days, I need to add an extra `'0'` so that it looks symmetrical. For instance, what I am getting now is `4/11/2014`, but I would like it to be `04/11/2014`. So how can I get the date be two digits by an additional zero in case of single digit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
('00' + tomorrow.getDate()).slice(-2)
```

Will get you what you want (slice with negative index, will start from the end).

Also, you can have `tomorrow` using the Date constructor directly:

```
var tomorrow = new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 3600 * 24));
// Date.now() returns current date in millisenconds
```

[Demo: `jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/n4e87x6k/2/)

Comment: Sorry couldn't get you. Can you create a fiddle please?

Comment: Worked like a Charm. Thanks. +1 for the effort . I hope it will not render 010 when the date is 10.

Comment: `('00' + '10') = '0010'`, `slice(-2)` will take the last 2 chars --> `'10'`.

Comment: One quick query .. The date displayed is of tomorrow and not today .. So any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = ((tomorrow.getDate() < 10) ? "0" : "") + tomorrow.getDate() + "/" + months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + "/" + tomorrow.getFullYear()
```

this should do the trick

Comment: But will this work when the date is 10 and should not render as 010? +1 for the effort.

Comment: Yes, this will work, you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/qto8qshx/    if you want to test out different days, just change the parameter of .setDate() :)

Comment: One quick query .. The date displayed is of tomorrow and not today .. So any ways to fix this?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to fix? the fiddle i gave was just for showing purposes, ignore the .setDate for usage

Comment: Thats fine, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714613/dynamic-javascript-date-pointing-date-for-tomorrow