# Dynamic javaScript date pointing date for tomorrow

Tags: javascript

I am using the below script to create dynamic date.

**The HTML:**

```
<span id="spanDate"></span>
```

**The Script:**

```
var months = ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07',
        '08','09','10','11','12'];       
        var tomorrow = new Date(Date.now() + (1000*3600*24));
        //tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*24));       
        document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = ('00' + tomorrow.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + "/" + tomorrow.getFullYear();
```

**[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/n4e87x6k/2/)**

What happens is that when I render this code, it displays me a date for the next day (i.e tomorrow) from my machine date and does not displays me today's date. Why is this happening?

Comment: What is expected output? Do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/n4e87x6k/4/

Comment: Expected output should be today's date which is similar to my machines date, but I am getting a date which is for tomorrow i.e one ahead from my machine.

Comment: Have you not tried `var tomorrow = new Date();` instead of `var tomorrow = new Date(Date.now() + (1000*3600*24));`?

Comment: And where is dynamic date when its showing same date every time?

Comment: -1 Even his variable name is tomorrow...

Comment: Down vote for what ?? Mr Downvoter .. atleast have the guts to convince your down vote

Comment: -1. What you're asking is basically the same as this: *Why does `console.log(1 + 1)` log `2` and not `1`?* Did you even look at your code?

Comment: I did @RuudLenders, but that has got nothing to do with the answer as what I am getting is purely different from what you are mentioning. I believe your point is not worth the downvote or else people will stop posting questions with the fear of losing their valuable earned reputation just for the sake of no point.

Comment: If you had closely read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904667/html-how-do-i-insert-dynamic-date-in-webpage) where you most probably copied "your" code from, you would have known that the questioner specifically asked for the current date **plus one day**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you add a day when you initialize your date?

```
 //You add 1000*3600*24 milliseconds: 1 day ===> outcome is tomorrow
 tomorrow.setTime(tomorrow.getTime() + (1000*3600*24));
```

Try

```
var tomorrow = new Date(Date.now());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n4e87x6k/3/

Maybe it's also usefull to change your parameter from "tomorrow" to "today" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you add a whole day to the current time on the Date constructor. If you want to display the current Date use

```
var today = new Date();
```

and replace

```
document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = ('00' + tomorrow.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + months[tomorrow.getMonth()] + "/" + tomorrow.getFullYear();
```

with

```
document.getElementById("spanDate").innerHTML = ('00' + today.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + months[today.getMonth()] + "/" + today.getFullYear();
```

Comment: +1 for your efforts. Works like a charm. Shall accept the other guy's answer, as he answered first.